# Regarding the use of events

Tags: python, events, pyqt4, signals-slots

I'm building a GUI in python 2.7 with pyqt4. I wanted to link a button to a script and someone provided me the following code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

# --- functions ---

def my_function(event=None):
    print 'Button clicked: event:', event
    print linetext.text()

    # run your code

# --- main ---

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

# add "layout manager"
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(vbox)

# add place for text
linetext = QtGui.QLineEdit(window)
vbox.addWidget(linetext)

# add button 
button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run", window)
vbox.addWidget(button)

# add function to button 
button.clicked.connect(my_function)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't understand why you would pass the `event=None` as an argument for `my_function`. When I run the script without the event parts it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not needed.

In Qt, events and signals/slots are two separate systems. Generally speaking, events ultimately come from *outside* of the application (e.g. keyboard presses, mouse moves, etc), whilst signals come from *within* the application.

A click is a combination of events (mouse-press + mouse-release), which are initially handled internally by Qt. The event handlers then emit the `clicked` signal whenever appropriate.

The `clicked` signal actually sends its *checked-state* (i.e. `True` or `False`), rather than an event object. But that is not really relevant in your script (that is, you don't need to provide an argument for it).